# How to tell if Break/Lunch starts and ends between shift start/end in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Excel VBA 2010:

We have schedules that run 24/7. I'd like some logic to test if the break/lunch start/end times fall within the shift start/end times. I don't want someone to schedule a break outside of their scheduled shift hours.

In addition I'd like to check if a break/lunch will run into another break or lunch duration. I don't want someone to schedule a break at say 10:00-10:15 while they have lunch schedule from 10:00 to 10:30.

Thank you in advance!

Here's a sample of my logic:

```
ShiftStart = Format("20:45", "hh:mm")
Brk1Start = Format("23:00", "hh:mm")
Brk1End = Format("23:15", "hh:mm")
Brk2Start = Format("04:15", "hh:mm")
Brk2End = Format("04:30", "hh:mm")
LunchBrk = Format("02:00", "hh:mm")
LunchBrkEnd = Format("03:00", "hh:mm")
ShiftEnd = Format("06:15", "hh:mm")

If Brk1Start <= ShiftStart Or Brk1Start >= ShiftEnd Or _
        Brk1End <= ShiftStart Or Brk1End >= ShiftEnd Then
        HighlightRed
End If
```

Comment: Instead of using strings for all your start/end times, use a `Date` type variable. Then these comparisons become straightforward.

Comment: I'd love to! Currently my sheet is set with a drop down for users to select the hour, then the next column is the minute selection. I then concatenate those together wtih ":" and then format it.  We were having loads of trouble with people entering data wrong.

Comment: That's all fine. So if cell A1 has the hours and B1 has the minutes, then in C1 use this formula `=TIMEVALUE(A1&":"&B1)`. Your C1 cell is now `Date` formatted.

Comment: I tried the formula and it doesn't work. I entered `=TIMEVALUE(E16&":"&F16)` and nothing but that text shows up in the cell. What would the If statement look like if it was Date formatted?

Comment: Use `CDate()` to convert your time from `String` to `Date` type, then compare it like numbers, as @PeterT said.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are!

```
Sub TestSchedule()

    ShiftStart = CDate("20:45")
    Brk1Start = CDate("23:00")
    Brk1End = CDate("23:15")
    Brk2Start = CDate("04:15")
    Brk2End = CDate("04:30")
    LunchBrk = CDate("02:00")
    LunchBrkEnd = CDate("03:00")
    ShiftEnd = CDate("06:15")

    MsgBox IsWithin(ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, Brk1Start, Brk1End)
    MsgBox IsWithin(ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, Brk2Start, Brk2End)
    MsgBox IsWithin(ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, LunchBrk, LunchBrkEnd)

    MsgBox IsWithin(ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, Brk1Start, Brk1End) And _
        IsWithin(ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, Brk2Start, Brk2End) And _
        IsWithin(ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, LunchBrk, LunchBrkEnd)

End Sub

Function IsWithin(dShiftStart, ByVal dShiftEnd, ByVal dBreakStart, ByVal dBreakEnd)
    If dShiftEnd < dShiftStart Then dShiftEnd = dShiftEnd + 1
    If dBreakEnd < dBreakStart Then dBreakEnd = dBreakEnd + 1
    If dBreakStart < dShiftStart Then
        dBreakStart = dBreakStart + 1
        dBreakEnd = dBreakEnd + 1
    End If
    IsWithin = (dBreakStart > dShiftStart) And (dBreakEnd < dShiftEnd)
End Function
```

**UPDATE**
In reply to your question in comment here is one more function `Function IsSeparate()` to check if two breaks are not overlapping, also `Sub Test()` preparing initial data nested arrays, and `Sub CheckSchedule()` performing all necessary checks.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ShiftStart, Brk1Start, Brk1End, Brk2Start, Brk2End, LunchBrk, LunchBrkEnd, ShiftEnd, arrBrk1, arrBrk2, arrLunch, arrBrks
    ' set time valuse
    ShiftStart = CDate("20:45")
    Brk1Start = CDate("23:00")
    Brk1End = CDate("23:15")
    Brk2Start = CDate("04:15")
    Brk2End = CDate("04:30")
    LunchBrk = CDate("02:00")
    LunchBrkEnd = CDate("03:00")
    ShiftEnd = CDate("06:15")
    ' push breaks into arrays
    arrBrk1 = Array(Brk1Start, Brk1End, "Break#1")
    arrBrk2 = Array(Brk2Start, Brk2End, "Break#2")
    arrLunch = Array(LunchBrk, LunchBrkEnd, "Lunch")
    ' push all break arrays into single consolidated array
    arrBrks = Array(arrBrk1, arrBrk2, arrLunch)
    ' pass shift start, shift end, and the array to check
    CheckSchedule ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, arrBrks
End Sub

Sub CheckSchedule(dShiftStart, dShiftEnd, arrBreaks)
    Dim r, i, j
    r = ""
    For i = 0 to UBound(arrBreaks)
        If Not IsWithin(dShiftStart, dShiftEnd, arrBreaks(i)(0), arrBreaks(i)(1)) Then r = r & arrBreaks(i)(2) & " is out of shift" & vbCrLf
        For j = i + 1 to UBound(arrBreaks)
            If Not IsSeparate(arrBreaks(i)(0), arrBreaks(i)(1), arrBreaks(j)(0), arrBreaks(j)(1)) Then r = r & arrBreaks(i)(2) & " and " & arrBreaks(j)(2) & " are overlapping" & vbCrLf
        Next
    Next
    If r = "" Then r = "No issues were found"
    MsgBox r
End Sub

Function IsSeparate(dStart1, dEnd1, dStart2, dEnd2)
    Select Case True
    Case dEnd1 < dStart1 And dEnd2 < dStart2
        IsSeparate = False
    Case dEnd1 < dStart1
        IsSeparate = dEnd2 < dStart1 And dStart2 > dEnd1
    Case dEnd2 < dStart2
        IsSeparate = dEnd1 < dStart2 And dStart1 > dEnd2
    Case Else
        IsSeparate = dEnd1 < dStart2 Or dEnd2 < dStart1
    End Select
End Function

Function IsWithin(dShiftStart, ByVal dShiftEnd, ByVal dBreakStart, ByVal dBreakEnd)
    If dShiftEnd < dShiftStart Then dShiftEnd = dShiftEnd + 1
    If dBreakEnd < dBreakStart Then dBreakEnd = dBreakEnd + 1
    If dBreakStart < dShiftStart Then
        dBreakStart = dBreakStart + 1
        dBreakEnd = dBreakEnd + 1
    End If
    IsWithin = dBreakStart > dShiftStart And dBreakEnd < dShiftEnd
End Function
```

Comment: What sort of function could I use to see if the Breaks/Lunch will start and/or end within another Break/Lunch?

Comment: I guess you want to check if one break intersects with any others?

Comment: Correct! I tried to modify the logic but it's not working properly.